# Unable to resume activity(containing a SupportMapFragment), NPE at R.id.map when resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I have a fragment which contains a map view that is defined in onResume as shown in the code below.  When I exit the fragment and come back or move around in different fragments and come back to this map fragment, I get no errors or problems. However, when I go to google maps app from a button I've provided below and come back to this fragment, it gives NPE at findFragmentById(R.id.map) and logcat says "unable to resume activity".

Edit: Whenever onCreateView is called, it works but when onResume or onStart is called it crashes. I got that wrong before. Edited.
    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

```
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2,
                container, false);


        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById
**NPE here**      (R.id.map)).getMap();
              ...
            }

    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f != null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
```

Here is the logcat:-

```
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.mapsapiv2demo/com.example.mapsapiv2demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2869)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2898)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at com.example.mapsapiv2demo.Fragment2.onResume(Fragment2.java:56)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1503)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1871)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:455)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:444)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5195)
06-07 21:32:43.295: E/AndroidRuntime(27112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
```

Comment: What happens when you just press HOME while showing this fragment and then return to the application?

Comment: ok I tried that and it crashes, turns out whenever oncreateview is called, it works but when onresume or onstart is called it crashes.

Comment: if I create the map in onCreatView, it doesnt crash but when resuming the application it shows a blank screen in place of the map. So I moved the map creation in onResume and have started getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing subfragment in `onPause` and when `onResume` is later called, it is not there and so the reason for NPE.

Another thing is that you should not put subfragments in xml. Always add them from code.

Yet another thing is that you should use [`getChildFragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) instead of `getFragmentManager` when adding fragment to fragment.

Take a look at code here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5064#c1 for an example.

**Edit:**

> **Note:** You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

from: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: OK so I did understand the problem. However, I don't want to add it at run time since I don't know how to set height & width properties of map-view fragment at run-time. I tried ChildFragmentManager but it was force closing with some new error and I didn't want to deal with yet another error so i reverted back to FragmentManager. I can't seem to figure out a solution now. How do I force it to call oncreateview from onresume method?

Comment: Also, I have to use XML because there is a header and footer in the layout and the map is sandwiched in between. From java code, seems like I can only make a map view that takes up the whole screen.